# nft vs iptables: inserting a rule at the top of a chain on multiple hosts

Tags: networking, firewall, nftables

I'm managing a number of hosts that rely on `nft` to manage the firewall. I need to insert a rule at the top of the `INPUT` chain on these hosts. Under `iptables`, this would be as simple as running, on every host:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 ...
```

But `nft` relies on "handles" to [insert a rule at a given position](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Simple_rule_management#Adding_a_rule_at_a_given_position), which is fine when working on a single host, but complicates the process when managing multiple hosts, because there's no guarantee that handles match across hosts.

For example, right now, at the beginning of the `INPUT` chain on two different hosts, I have on one host:

```
        chain INPUT { # handle 1
                type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
                iifname "ovn-k8s-gw0"  counter packets 977422 bytes 167040650 accept # handle 11
```

And on the other:

```
        chain INPUT { # handle 1
                type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
                iifname "ovn-k8s-gw0"  counter packets 55820 bytes 6735009 accept # handle 12
```

Note that the first rule on one host is handle `11` and on the other it's `12`.

I guess I could get the handle of the first rule with something like...

```
nft list chain filter INPUT -n -a | sed -n 4p | awk '{print $NF}'
```

...but that smells bad. Is there a way to instruct `nft` to insert a rule by absolute position rather than by handle?

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be simpler than I thought.

The `nft insert rule` command will by default insert a rule at the top of the chain if there is no `position` argument.